# how to trigger a button command in c# without clicking it ? (.NET MAUI)

Tags: c#, .net, button, maui

I am trying to execute the command of a button just in c# . but it's not happening. here is what I tried

```
 Command = new Command(async () =>
                        {

                            var page = new NewPage2();
                            var inputEntry = page.FindByName<Entry>("inputEntry");
                            inputEntry.Text = item;
                            var button = page.FindByName<Button>("sendButton");
                            button.Command?.Execute(null);
                            
                            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
                        })
```

as you can see i create a page and get the entry in that page and put the text (item) in the entry everything until here work fine but when i execute button command to send it , it doesn't work until I click it .

Comment: you are trying to execute a command before the page has appeared.  It would make more sense to do this in `page2`s `OnAppearing`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution . I changed the line of

```
button.Command?.Execute(null);
```

by this line

```
page.OnSendClickedAsync(button, EventArgs.Empty);
```

remember to change OnSendClickedAsync by the method you calling in "Clicked " or in "Command", and of course the name of page and the name of button .